# Integracion de Firebase a Flutter hace que el app deje de funcionar

Tags: firebase, flutter, build.gradle

He seguido todos los pasos para integrar firebase a mi aplicación de flutter, pero cuando lo corro desde mi windows obtengo el siguiente error:

p.d. Funciona perfectamente en un mac y antes de añadir las lineas de codigo a los build.gradle que necesita firebase.

> - Error running Gradle: ProcessException: Process "C:\Users\[user]\[project]\android\gradlew.bat" exited abnormally:
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - Where: Build file 'C:\Users\[user]\[project]\android\app\build.gradle' line: 24
> - What went wrong: A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
>
>   > ASCII
> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
> - Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
>
> BUILD FAILED in 1s   Command:
>   C:\Users\[user]\[project]\android\gradlew.bat app:properties
>
> Please review your Gradle project setup in the android/ folder.

Comment: Welcome, This is a site in Spanish, please translate your answer.

Comment: ¿Las configuraciones del gradle son las mismas?

Comment: Hola, haz tenido algún avance de como resolver este problema? Me ha surgido este error y quisiera saber si lograste resolverlo y como.
Gracias

Comment: Acabo de publicar la solucion que me funciono

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLUCION:

En proyecto/android/build.gradle:

> Cambiar la version de google services a 3.2.1

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"

    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.1'   
}
```

> Agregar este codigo a subprojects

```
subprojects {
    project.configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { details ->
            if (details.requested.group == 'androidx.core'
                    && !details.requested.name.contains('androidx') ) {
                details.useVersion "1.0.2"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

En proyecto/android/app/build.gradle:

> Agregar [multiDexEnabled true] a defaultConfig

```
defaultConfig {
    // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
    applicationId "com.example.proyecto"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
    versionName flutterVersionName
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    multiDexEnabled true
}
```

En proyecto/android/gradle/gradle.properties:

> Agregar la linea [android.useAndroidX=true]

Answer (score 0):

he tenido ese mismo problema y al parecer es un problema de repositorios cuando se crea el proyecto en mac. La solución que he encontrado es generar un nuevo proyecto vació en Windows y trasladar el código copiandolo.

Comment: Que parte del nuevo proyecto generado en windows debo conservar? Ya que si solo copio la carpeta lib y el pubspec.yaml se omiten el codigo y archivos para conectar con firebase. Gracias por ciertoo!